# I would like to separate each elements of this list which this list defines as a string in python

Tags: python

This is what I have:

```py
undesirable = ['0   0.8770833333333333   0.3712962962962963   0.03567708333333333   0.04537037037037037']
```

And this is my desired output:

```py
desirable = [0 , 0.8770833333333333 ,  0.3712962962962963 , 0.03567708333333333 ,0.04537037037037037]
```

How can I convert the undesirable list into the desirable one?

Comment: Don't build that undesirable thing in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

```py
undesirable = ['0 0.8770833333333333 0.3712962962962963 0.03567708333333333 0.04537037037037037']
desirable = [float(f) for f in undesirable[0].split(" ")]
```

Explanation:

```py
undesirable[0] #Gets the "first" item in the list (given that undesirable is a list containing a single string. This returns the string "0 0.877 ... 0.04"
.split(" ") # Splits the string on the space (" ") character, returns a list of the pieces. 
float() # Casts the string representations of floats to floats.
```

This uses the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
undesirable = ['0 0.8770833333333333 0.3712962962962963 0.03567708333333333 0.04537037037037037']
desirable_str = undesirable[0].split(" ")
print(desirable_str)
desirable = [float(s) for s in desirable_str]
print(desirable)
```

Output:
['0', '0.8770833333333333', '0.3712962962962963', '0.03567708333333333', '0.04537037037037037']
[0.0, 0.8770833333333333, 0.3712962962962963, 0.03567708333333333, 0.04537037037037037]